# UIScrollView nested within UIPageViewController slide

Tags: ios, swift, uigesturerecognizer

I have a pretty standard `UIPageViewController` that loads 3 individual `UIViewController`s to swipe through.

One of these `UIViewController`s needs a UIScrollView that still functions without triggering the `UIPageViewController`'s gesture recognizer.

How can I limit the gesture only to the `UIScrollView` if that's where the touch was initiated so it doesn't trigger a transition?

Here's a diagram of the setup:
[image]

UIPageViewController source:

```
class MyPageViewController: UIPageViewController
{
    fileprivate lazy var pages: [UIViewController] = {
        return [
            self.getViewController(withIdentifier: "MyPage1"),
            self.getViewController(withIdentifier: "MyPage2"),
            self.getViewController(withIdentifier: "MyPage3"),
        ]
    }()

    fileprivate func getViewController(withIdentifier identifier: String) -> UIViewController
    {
        return UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil).instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: identifier)
    }

    var imageView: UIImageView?
    var backgroundVideo : VideoBackground!

    override func viewDidLoad()
    {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        self.dataSource = self
        self.delegate   = self as? UIPageViewControllerDelegate

        if let firstVC = pages.first
        {
            setViewControllers([firstVC], direction: .forward, animated: true, completion: nil)
        }
    }

}

extension MyPageViewController: UIPageViewControllerDataSource
{
    func pageViewController(_ pageViewController: UIPageViewController, viewControllerBefore viewController: UIViewController) -> UIViewController? {

        guard let viewControllerIndex = pages.index(of: viewController) else { return nil }

        let previousIndex = viewControllerIndex - 1

        guard previousIndex >= 0 else { return nil        }

        guard pages.count > previousIndex else { return nil        }

        return pages[previousIndex]
    }

    func pageViewController(_ pageViewController: UIPageViewController, viewControllerAfter viewController: UIViewController) -> UIViewController?
    {
        guard let viewControllerIndex = pages.index(of: viewController) else { return nil }
        let nextIndex = viewControllerIndex + 1
        guard nextIndex < pages.count else { return nil        }
        guard pages.count > nextIndex else { return nil         }
        return pages[nextIndex]
    }

    private func setupPageControl() {
        let appearance = UIPageControl.appearance()
        appearance.pageIndicatorTintColor = UIColor.black
        appearance.currentPageIndicatorTintColor = UIColor.white
        appearance.backgroundColor = UIColor.clear
        appearance.isOpaque = false
    }

    func presentationCount(for pageViewController: UIPageViewController) -> Int {
        setupPageControl()
        return self.pages.count
    }

    func presentationIndex(for pageViewController: UIPageViewController) -> Int {
        return 0
    }

    override func viewDidLayoutSubviews() {
        super.viewDidLayoutSubviews()
        for view in self.view.subviews {
            if view is UIScrollView {
                view.frame = UIScreen.main.bounds
            } else if view is UIPageControl {
                view.backgroundColor = UIColor.clear
            }
        }
    }

}

extension MyPageViewController: UIPageViewControllerDelegate {}
```

Comment: This is not quite clear... Do you want to only move from VC-1 to VC-2 by some means other than swiping?

Comment: I just want the UIScrollView to work like a typically scrollview, where there's oversized content in that area what I want to be able to move around *without* triggering the gesture to transition to the next page.

Comment: Have you added content to it? If you do (and you have the constraints setup correctly) you *will* be able to scroll around within the scroll view. If you scroll left to the edge of the scroll view's content, then it will, of course, scroll to the next page.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is an example Storyboard that should run without any edits to your posted code (replace the source of `Main.storyboard` with the following).

The first VC has a scroll view, which contains a stack view with 6 labels. The stack view has vertical `Spacing = 160` so you should get plenty of vertical scrolling, and its width is set to the scroll view's width + 120, so you'll also get horizontal scrolling.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<document type="com.apple.InterfaceBuilder3.CocoaTouch.Storyboard.XIB" version="3.0" toolsVersion="14868" targetRuntime="iOS.CocoaTouch" propertyAccessControl="none" useAutolayout="YES" useTraitCollections="YES" useSafeAreas="YES" colorMatched="YES" initialViewController="bGW-rc-7aL">
    <device id="retina4_7" orientation="portrait" appearance="light"/>
    <dependencies>
        <deployment identifier="iOS"/>
        <plugIn identifier="com.apple.InterfaceBuilder.IBCocoaTouchPlugin" version="14824"/>
        <capability name="Safe area layout guides" minToolsVersion="9.0"/>
        <capability name="documents saved in the Xcode 8 format" minToolsVersion="8.0"/>
    </dependencies>
    <scenes>
        <!--My Page View Controller-->
        <scene sceneID="bIF-VX-tZJ">
            <objects>
                <pageViewController autoresizesArchivedViewToFullSize="NO" transitionStyle="scroll" navigationOrientation="horizontal" spineLocation="none" id="bGW-rc-7aL" customClass="MyPageViewController" customModule="X11SwiftScratch" customModuleProvider="target" sceneMemberID="viewController"/>
                <placeholder placeholderIdentifier="IBFirstResponder" id="Bbm-jJ-ZTN" userLabel="First Responder" customClass="UIResponder" sceneMemberID="firstResponder"/>
            </objects>
            <point key="canvasLocation" x="141" y="154"/>
        </scene>
        <!--View Controller-->
        <scene sceneID="aDQ-BH-6ga">
            <objects>
                <viewController storyboardIdentifier="MyPage1" id="0X7-Tt-JCc" sceneMemberID="viewController">
                    <view key="view" contentMode="scaleToFill" id="ORv-uN-p9a">
                        <rect key="frame" x="0.0" y="0.0" width="375" height="667"/>
                        <autoresizingMask key="autoresizingMask" widthSizable="YES" heightSizable="YES"/>
                        <subviews>
                            <scrollView clipsSubviews="YES" multipleTouchEnabled="YES" contentMode="scaleToFill" translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints="NO" id="uhG-aG-m6P">
                                <rect key="frame" x="20" y="20" width="335" height="607"/>
                                <subviews>
                                    <stackView opaque="NO" contentMode="scaleToFill" axis="vertical" spacing="160" translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints="NO" id="oBC-6H-LIT">
                                        <rect key="frame" x="16" y="16" width="455" height="923"/>
                                        <subviews>
                                            <label opaque="NO" userInteractionEnabled="NO" contentMode="left" horizontalHuggingPriority="251" verticalHuggingPriority="1000" text="Label 1 of 6 (Left Aligned)" textAlignment="natural" lineBreakMode="tailTruncation" baselineAdjustment="alignBaselines" adjustsFontSizeToFit="NO" translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints="NO" id="wdR-VH-nME">
                                                <rect key="frame" x="0.0" y="0.0" width="455" height="20.5"/>
                                                <color key="backgroundColor" red="0.45138680930000002" green="0.99309605359999997" blue="1" alpha="1" colorSpace="custom" customColorSpace="sRGB"/>
                                                <fontDescription key="fontDescription" type="system" pointSize="17"/>
                                                <nil key="textColor"/>
                                                <nil key="highlightedColor"/>
                                            </label>
                                            <label opaque="NO" userInteractionEnabled="NO" contentMode="left" horizontalHuggingPriority="251" verticalHuggingPriority="1000" text="Label 2 of 6" textAlignment="center" lineBreakMode="tailTruncation" baselineAdjustment="alignBaselines" adjustsFontSizeToFit="NO" translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints="NO" id="4e4-gU-jmU">
                                                <rect key="frame" x="0.0" y="180.5" width="455" height="20.5"/>
                                                <color key="backgroundColor" red="0.45138680930000002" green="0.99309605359999997" blue="1" alpha="1" colorSpace="custom" customColorSpace="sRGB"/>
                                                <fontDescription key="fontDescription" type="system" pointSize="17"/>
                                                <nil key="textColor"/>
                                                <nil key="highlightedColor"/>
                                            </label>
                                            <label opaque="NO" userInteractionEnabled="NO" contentMode="left" horizontalHuggingPriority="251" verticalHuggingPriority="1000" text="Label 3 of 6" textAlignment="center" lineBreakMode="tailTruncation" baselineAdjustment="alignBaselines" adjustsFontSizeToFit="NO" translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints="NO" id="RwZ-xg-eTU">
                                                <rect key="frame" x="0.0" y="361" width="455" height="20.5"/>
                                                <color key="backgroundColor" red="0.45138680930000002" green="0.99309605359999997" blue="1" alpha="1" colorSpace="custom" customColorSpace="sRGB"/>
                                                <fontDescription key="fontDescription" type="system" pointSize="17"/>
                                                <nil key="textColor"/>
                                                <nil key="highlightedColor"/>
                                            </label>
                                            <label opaque="NO" userInteractionEnabled="NO" contentMode="left" horizontalHuggingPriority="251" verticalHuggingPriority="1000" text="Label 4 of 6" textAlignment="center" lineBreakMode="tailTruncation" baselineAdjustment="alignBaselines" adjustsFontSizeToFit="NO" translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints="NO" id="pCZ-C2-chu">
                                                <rect key="frame" x="0.0" y="541.5" width="455" height="20.5"/>
                                                <color key="backgroundColor" red="0.45138680930000002" green="0.99309605359999997" blue="1" alpha="1" colorSpace="custom" customColorSpace="sRGB"/>
                                                <fontDescription key="fontDescription" type="system" pointSize="17"/>
                                                <nil key="textColor"/>
                                                <nil key="highlightedColor"/>
                                            </label>
                                            <label opaque="NO" userInteractionEnabled="NO" contentMode="left" horizontalHuggingPriority="251" verticalHuggingPriority="1000" text="Label 5 of 6" textAlignment="center" lineBreakMode="tailTruncation" baselineAdjustment="alignBaselines" adjustsFontSizeToFit="NO" translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints="NO" id="Eio-bZ-5G0">
                                                <rect key="frame" x="0.0" y="722" width="455" height="20.5"/>
                                                <color key="backgroundColor" red="0.45138680930000002" green="0.99309605359999997" blue="1" alpha="1" colorSpace="custom" customColorSpace="sRGB"/>
                                                <fontDescription key="fontDescription" type="system" pointSize="17"/>
                                                <nil key="textColor"/>
                                                <nil key="highlightedColor"/>
                                            </label>
                                            <label opaque="NO" userInteractionEnabled="NO" contentMode="left" horizontalHuggingPriority="251" verticalHuggingPriority="1000" text="Label 6 of 6 (Right Aligned)" textAlignment="right" lineBreakMode="tailTruncation" baselineAdjustment="alignBaselines" adjustsFontSizeToFit="NO" translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints="NO" id="r8L-JP-uyd">
                                                <rect key="frame" x="0.0" y="902.5" width="455" height="20.5"/>
                                                <color key="backgroundColor" red="0.45138680930000002" green="0.99309605359999997" blue="1" alpha="1" colorSpace="custom" customColorSpace="sRGB"/>
                                                <fontDescription key="fontDescription" type="system" pointSize="17"/>
                                                <nil key="textColor"/>
                                                <nil key="highlightedColor"/>
                                            </label>
                                        </subviews>
                                    </stackView>
                                </subviews>
                                <color key="backgroundColor" systemColor="systemPinkColor" red="1" green="0.17647058823529413" blue="0.33333333333333331" alpha="1" colorSpace="custom" customColorSpace="sRGB"/>
                                <constraints>
                                    <constraint firstItem="A0Z-27-E6L" firstAttribute="trailing" secondItem="oBC-6H-LIT" secondAttribute="trailing" constant="16" id="7BS-Ej-D46"/>
                                    <constraint firstItem="A0Z-27-E6L" firstAttribute="bottom" secondItem="oBC-6H-LIT" secondAttribute="bottom" constant="16" id="7bn-Ov-tgf"/>
                                    <constraint firstItem="oBC-6H-LIT" firstAttribute="leading" secondItem="A0Z-27-E6L" secondAttribute="leading" constant="16" id="GCP-KY-b7Z"/>
                                    <constraint firstItem="oBC-6H-LIT" firstAttribute="top" secondItem="A0Z-27-E6L" secondAttribute="top" constant="16" id="QuF-Rm-AkK"/>
                                    <constraint firstItem="oBC-6H-LIT" firstAttribute="width" secondItem="uhG-aG-m6P" secondAttribute="width" constant="120" id="anG-6u-Yca"/>
                                </constraints>
                                <viewLayoutGuide key="contentLayoutGuide" id="A0Z-27-E6L"/>
                                <viewLayoutGuide key="frameLayoutGuide" id="BCl-PX-Sdc"/>
                            </scrollView>
                        </subviews>
                        <color key="backgroundColor" red="0.0" green="0.97680455450000003" blue="0.0" alpha="1" colorSpace="custom" customColorSpace="sRGB"/>
                        <constraints>
                            <constraint firstItem="uhG-aG-m6P" firstAttribute="leading" secondItem="EcH-SV-2jG" secondAttribute="leading" constant="20" id="01z-qf-UXc"/>
                            <constraint firstItem="EcH-SV-2jG" firstAttribute="trailing" secondItem="uhG-aG-m6P" secondAttribute="trailing" constant="20" id="3dg-7y-1df"/>
                            <constraint firstItem="uhG-aG-m6P" firstAttribute="top" secondItem="EcH-SV-2jG" secondAttribute="top" constant="20" id="Ag3-kQ-VZi"/>
                            <constraint firstItem="EcH-SV-2jG" firstAttribute="bottom" secondItem="uhG-aG-m6P" secondAttribute="bottom" constant="40" id="Kv7-a8-Cbw"/>
                        </constraints>
                        <viewLayoutGuide key="safeArea" id="EcH-SV-2jG"/>
                    </view>
                </viewController>
                <placeholder placeholderIdentifier="IBFirstResponder" id="xno-2J-adv" userLabel="First Responder" customClass="UIResponder" sceneMemberID="firstResponder"/>
            </objects>
            <point key="canvasLocation" x="-505" y="839"/>
        </scene>
        <!--View Controller-->
        <scene sceneID="eCj-2x-uVh">
            <objects>
                <viewController storyboardIdentifier="MyPage2" id="ds7-6v-s81" sceneMemberID="viewController">
                    <view key="view" contentMode="scaleToFill" id="LOr-ii-ZPH">
                        <rect key="frame" x="0.0" y="0.0" width="375" height="667"/>
                        <autoresizingMask key="autoresizingMask" widthSizable="YES" heightSizable="YES"/>
                        <subviews>
                            <label opaque="NO" userInteractionEnabled="NO" contentMode="left" horizontalHuggingPriority="251" verticalHuggingPriority="251" text="MyPage2" textAlignment="natural" lineBreakMode="tailTruncation" baselineAdjustment="alignBaselines" adjustsFontSizeToFit="NO" translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints="NO" id="UGr-eF-8Ji">
                                <rect key="frame" x="106.5" y="309.5" width="162" height="48"/>
                                <fontDescription key="fontDescription" type="system" pointSize="40"/>
                                <nil key="textColor"/>
                                <nil key="highlightedColor"/>
                            </label>
                        </subviews>
                        <color key="backgroundColor" red="0.46202266219999999" green="0.83828371759999998" blue="1" alpha="1" colorSpace="custom" customColorSpace="sRGB"/>
                        <constraints>
                            <constraint firstItem="UGr-eF-8Ji" firstAttribute="centerY" secondItem="LOr-ii-ZPH" secondAttribute="centerY" id="D1t-8l-i7e"/>
                            <constraint firstItem="UGr-eF-8Ji" firstAttribute="centerX" secondItem="LOr-ii-ZPH" secondAttribute="centerX" id="E43-KJ-us0"/>
                        </constraints>
                        <viewLayoutGuide key="safeArea" id="Uuj-0T-WQB"/>
                    </view>
                </viewController>
                <placeholder placeholderIdentifier="IBFirstResponder" id="q5w-TC-x2k" userLabel="First Responder" customClass="UIResponder" sceneMemberID="firstResponder"/>
            </objects>
            <point key="canvasLocation" x="140" y="839"/>
        </scene>
        <!--View Controller-->
        <scene sceneID="Zpi-8N-Mbb">
            <objects>
                <viewController storyboardIdentifier="MyPage3" id="TR7-PG-Lwi" sceneMemberID="viewController">
                    <view key="view" contentMode="scaleToFill" id="ivN-Bt-RDV">
                        <rect key="frame" x="0.0" y="0.0" width="375" height="667"/>
                        <autoresizingMask key="autoresizingMask" widthSizable="YES" heightSizable="YES"/>
                        <subviews>
                            <label opaque="NO" userInteractionEnabled="NO" contentMode="left" horizontalHuggingPriority="251" verticalHuggingPriority="251" text="MyPage3" textAlignment="natural" lineBreakMode="tailTruncation" baselineAdjustment="alignBaselines" adjustsFontSizeToFit="NO" translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints="NO" id="qNc-nl-0lY">
                                <rect key="frame" x="106" y="309.5" width="163" height="48"/>
                                <fontDescription key="fontDescription" type="system" pointSize="40"/>
                                <nil key="textColor"/>
                                <nil key="highlightedColor"/>
                            </label>
                        </subviews>
                        <color key="backgroundColor" systemColor="systemYellowColor" red="1" green="0.80000000000000004" blue="0.0" alpha="1" colorSpace="custom" customColorSpace="sRGB"/>
                        <constraints>
                            <constraint firstItem="qNc-nl-0lY" firstAttribute="centerX" secondItem="ivN-Bt-RDV" secondAttribute="centerX" id="UvZ-bd-OYw"/>
                            <constraint firstItem="qNc-nl-0lY" firstAttribute="centerY" secondItem="ivN-Bt-RDV" secondAttribute="centerY" id="wGO-1o-zJs"/>
                        </constraints>
                        <viewLayoutGuide key="safeArea" id="ekN-ct-m1b"/>
                    </view>
                </viewController>
                <placeholder placeholderIdentifier="IBFirstResponder" id="ahl-iN-Pfs" userLabel="First Responder" customClass="UIResponder" sceneMemberID="firstResponder"/>
            </objects>
            <point key="canvasLocation" x="798" y="839"/>
        </scene>
    </scenes>
</document>
```

Comment: Thanks for the example - you were right, it works out of the box, and I had something wrong with my configuration that was preventing it from scrolling like normal.

Answer (score -2):

If the standard properties of the scrollView such as delaying the touch in the page controller don't work, but I think they should, `scrollView` inside a `scrollView` usually works fine, you can always override the [hitTest](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uiview/1622469-hittest) method and use it to decide which of the scrollViews should receive the touch. Just check if the `CGPoint` is inside your inner scrollview, and if so, return that scrollView, otherwise, return your superview.